# What is the puppet way to send configurations along with request from the puppet agent

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I want to make some dynamic configurations details in the puppet master side before it makes a deployment on puppet agent. So I want to send significant amount of configuration details along with the request of the agent to master. Is there a proper way to do this in puppet ?

Regards,
Malintha Adiakri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! There is facter. This is how I use it and what I find most robust but there are other ways to define new facts.

For example if you want to add role of the server then you can do
`export FACTER_ROLE=jenkins`

Now you can see that command `facter role` will print jenkins. Yay!
After running puppet agent all facts known to system will be passed to thenpuppetmaster. Be aware that service puppet will not know fact that you just defined because it runs in other scope.

I put my facts in file .facts and source it before apply.
This is my script that runs from cron:

`#!/bin/bash
source /root/.facts
puppet agent -t --server puppetmaster.example.com --pluginsync`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I run the command "sudo puppet agent --test" to triger the agent node. According to my understanding if we want to send the "FACTOR_ROLE" attribute to the puppet agent we can do it by executing "sudo puppet agent --test export FACTER_ROLE=jenkins" command in the agent side. Am I correct in this case ?

Comment: "pluginsync" does sending facters to the master here ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The magic here is source .facts file which will have export like `export FACTER_ROLE=jenkins`

Comment: Then How can we get the sent attributes from puppet master end? for ex: for the FACTOR_ROLE case what is the command should be executed in puppet master side ?

Comment: @Malintha for this direction you need custom facts, for which "pluginsync" does indeed play a part. If only someone would elaborate on this concept in a full fludged answer *hint,hint* ;-)

Comment: It is in puppetmaster catalog. To easily look through the data install PuppetDB and in manifest you can use it as variable $::role

Answer (score 2):

While the previous answer is correct, I'm opening this as a new one because it's significant. Defining `FACTER_factname` variables in the agent's environment is a nice and quick way to override some facts. If you wish to rely on your own facts for production purposes, you should look to [custom facts](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html) instead.

In its basic form, you use it by deploying Ruby code snippets to your boxen. For an easier approach, take special note of [external facts](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html#external-facts). Those are probably the best solution for your problem.

Also note that as of [Facter 2](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.0/release_notes.html) you can contain complex data structures in your facts and don't have to serialize everything into strings. If the amount of data from the agent is high, as you emphasize, that may be helpful.